# How to restrict api to an iOS version say just 10

Tags: swift

I want to be able to only allow a api to be called if the version is 10.*.  I know usually we use @available(10.0, *), but this means 10 and above.

How do i restrict 10 to <11?

Here is the persudo code:

```
if device is ios10 but less than 11 {
//Do this only for iOS10.*
}
```

Comment: Update your question with an example (even if just pseudo code). What do you want done if it's iOS 11 or iOS 9?

Comment: By example, I mean show a real example of an API. And what should happen if the device is not iOS 10?

Comment: So basically I want to beable to execute a piece of code only for ios10.*, otherwise I don't run it.  And i want to know how to restrict that code to run only for iOS 10.*.      So the persudo code is actually exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What should happen if something that's not iOS 10 tries to access the API?

Comment: Say if I'm running iOS 11, then that code should not be executed.  So I need to know how to restrict it to be only for iOS10

Comment: Again, show a real example. I can't think of any logical reason why you would only want something to run under a specific version of iOS.

Comment: Yeah the reason is that there is a weird UI bug that only happens in iOS10 and not anything else.

Comment: @mskw That is almost invariably something the developer is responsible for fixing...

Comment: This seem exception. iPad's uisearchbar for ios10 removes the cancel button, but for ios11 it includes.  So i need to customize for ios10 and add a cancel button based on requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `#available` instead of `@available`, just tested this and it seems to do what you need:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    // leave blank if you don't need to do anything here
} else if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    print("You're on iOS 10!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code:

```
let os = ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion

switch (os.majorVersion, os.minorVersion) {
case (10, 0): // iOS 10.0
    // Do your code
default:
    break // Some other version
}
```

Or if you want to use for all 10.* versions of OS, then simply skip minor version:

```
let os = ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion

if os.majorVersion == 10 {
    // Do your code
}
```

Comment: If you would like to mach any minor version in your switch `case (10, _):`

Comment: @LeoDabus Or just do `if os.majorVersion == 10`. No need for a `switch`.

Comment: @rmaddy of course I am just showing how to mach any minor version in case he needs to use a switch with both versions